# Adding image on the top of bar in chartjs

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, bar-chart

I was using a different chart on my site which was causing some issues so we migrated to chartjs. Everything works fine but I have one requirement which I cannot find in chartjs.

In the site I am working on, the user gives an assessment and it shows the graph based on the assessment results.

So in the assessment, there is a question "Are you feeling exacerbation?" If the user selects yes then in the graph it shows an image above that bar like below image.

[image]

In the picture you can see "E" above the two bars.

I want to achieve the same in chartjs. Is it possible? If not then can you guys suggest a way to notify the user that they have selected "exacerbation".

Thank you

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Comment: @ArigatoManga No Arigato, I didn't find any solution. I think it's not possible in chartjs. I had to use a different chart.

Comment: after a long try i was able to do it.. but don't know if that will be useful for you now

Comment: Please answer it here, It can be helpful to others

Comment: How to Add an Image on Top of the Bars in Chart.js: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfR2tLYaxxQ

Answer (score 5):

You can place images on top of individual bars using [chartjs-plugin-labels](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-labels).

Please have a look at the following runnable code snippet:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [25, 59, 80, 76],
      fill: false,
      backgroundColor: ['rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)', 'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)', 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)'],
      borderColor: ['rgb(255, 99, 132)', 'rgb(255, 159, 64)', 'rgb(255, 205, 86)', 'rgb(75, 192, 192)', 'rgb(54, 162, 235)'],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      labels: {
        render: 'image',
        textMargin: 10,
        images: [
          {
            src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMtU.png',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
          },
          null, 
          {
            src: 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EMtU.png',
            width: 20,
            height: 20
          },
          null
        ]
      }
    },
    layout: {
      padding: {
        top: 30
      }
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/emn178/chartjs-plugin-labels/src/chartjs-plugin-labels.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="10" height="6"></canvas>
```

Comment: how can implement this for horizontalBar ? it is just working for vertical bar